# Java Programming - method setting variable to false

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having my first few lessons in Java programming. I have been asked me to design a method that sets a variable to false. How do I go about writing the code? I've given an attempt below but I know it is far from correct.
Code below

```
public exitHall(Boolean onPremises == false);
```

For context, the question asks me to create an exitHall method, which sets a variable to false.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Remember to always use the `private` keyword when using variables like these. This ensures code integrity, as demonstrated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236259/java-programming-method-setting-variable-to-false/64236420#64236420)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a specific method for setting the variable to false like so:

```
public void exitHall(){
    this.onPremises=false;
}
```

Then you can have a getter method like so:

```
public boolean isOnPremises(){
    return this.onPremises();
}
```

Keep in mind you do need to define the variable **onPremises** like so:

```
public class BanquetHall{
    private boolean onPremises;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

We set it to **private**, because normally we don't want any other class to modify it without accessing the setter method. This ensures **code integrity**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a boolean variable, for example :

```
boolean onPremises;
```

Setter and Getters :

```
public boolean isOnPremises(){return this.onPremises;}

public void setOnPremises(boolean onPremises){this.onPremises = onPremises;}
```

If you want to set a variable value in a method then use this :

```
public void exitHall(boolean onPremises) {
    this.onPremises = onPremises;
    //any additional code required in this method
}
```

Comment: The question asks to create a method exitHall() which sets the variable to false

Comment: modified the answer, basically you just need to set the boolean variable value.

Answer (score -1):

```
   
        Boolean onPremises; //default value false
    
    
    public void setOnPremises(Boolean status){
          this.onPremises = status;
         
      }  //this method will help you to change the boolean status
    
     public boolean getOnPremises(){
          System.out.println(onPremises);
          return onPremises;
        
      }  //this method will help to get the current boolean status
```